# Undefined variable: in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to Display data on Laravel view page from database.

but it shows nothing to me

this is the code on `.blade.php` file:-

```
   <tbody>
   @if(isset($Us))
       @foreach($Us as $row)
           <tr>
               <td>{{ $row->id ?? '-'}}</td>
               <td>{{ $row->name ?? '-' }}</td>
               <td>{{ $row->email ?? '-'}}</td>
           </tr>
       @endforeach
   @endif
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Code on `AdminController.php`:

```
public function index()
{
    $Us = users::all()->toArray();
    return view('master')->with(['Us'=> $Us]);
}
```

and on `user.php`:

```
class Us extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','name','email'];

    public function category(){
        $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

i wanted to show database info to admin page

Thank you

Comment: why are you converting it to the array instead of using the collection that gets returned?

Comment: also, your user model is named "Us"...but you're trying to call "users::all()"...change it to "Us::all()" and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: side note: `Us@category` should return that `belongsTo`

Comment: i have done that before but it does not shows ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your model name to `User` instead of `Us`
and `users::all()` to `User::all()`

Answer (score 0):

You have converted the Eloquent Collection to an array which converts all the model instances it contains to arrays. In your Blade file you are trying to access the elements of the array as objects when they are also arrays. Use the syntax for accessing an array by index, `$array['index']`, instead of an object's property, `$object->property`:

```
<td>{{ $row['id'] ?? '-'}}</td>
<td>{{ $row['name'] ?? '-' }}</td>
<td>{{ $row['email'] ?? '-'}}</td>
```

Would probably be easier to just not convert the Collection to an array with `toArray`.

Demonstration of the issue:

```
$a = ['a' => 'A'];

dump($a->a ?? '-');
dump($a['a'] ?? '-');
```